# Optimize Finding Words in Paragraph

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I'm searching for words in a paragraph but it takes ages with long paragraphs. Hence, I want to remove the words after I find it in the paragraph to shorten the number of words I have to go through. Or if there's a better way to make this efficient do tell!

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (String word : wordList) {
    String regex = ".*\\b" + Pattern.quote(word) + "\\b.*"; 
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(paragraph);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found: " + word);
        list.add(word);
    }
}
```

For example, lets say my `wordList` has the following values `"apple","hungry","pie"`

And my `paragraph` is `"I ate an apple, but I am still hungry, so I will eat pie"`

I want to find the words in `wordList` in the `paragraph` and eliminate them in the hopes of making the above code faster

Comment: `I want to remove the words` ... to which _words_ are you referring?  Can you show us what you mean by way of sample data?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I made the edits to provide an example, sorry!

Comment: @ScaryWombat I'm not sure what you mean, I'm not manipulating a set? Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you are saying

Comment: The regex engine is just going to parse your input string from start to end.  So removing things won't really speed up the search process I would imagine.

Comment: Why don't you try to `match` based upon multiple `words` see https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-extract-multiple-groups-patterns-string-regex  or  https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch05s02.html

Comment: @ScaryWombat hmm the second link looks very promising if I can translate it to Java. I'll see if that speeds things up. I have wordList and paragraph on the order of 500-1000 words so If i could search for 500 words at once that'd be nice. The program is also threaded!

Comment: You will make your code way faster by mere changing the regex to `String regex = "\\b" + Pattern.quote(word) + "\\b";`. although since you have `Pattern.quote`, it must be `String regex = "(?<!\\w)" + Pattern.quote(word) + "(?!\\w)";`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the two different snippets you provided seem very different? Could you maybe explain the difference between `String regex = "\\b" + Pattern.quote(word) + "\\b";` and `String regex = "(?<!\\w)" + Pattern.quote(word) + "(?!\\w)";`

Comment: @dude8998 There is little difference, however, `"\\b\\+test\\b"` will never match anything in `"my +test test"` because there must be a letter, or digit, or `_` before `+test`. However, `"(?<!\\w)\\+test(?!\\w)"` will match `+test` in that string. To match partial strings, you need to use `.find()` method, not `.matches()`.

Comment: Ok, I got what you need. Try [**this code on your side**](https://ideone.com/J9olAb), let me know via a comment with `@Wiktor` and if it works, I will post with explanations. And if you only have words in the word list that consist of letters, digits or `_`s, you may use a [**lighter version**](https://ideone.com/h77G9d).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the words list is very simple! Always uppercase letters, hyphens, maybe digits, and occasionally (/ ) slashes. I will try your code and get back to you unless this information changes things

Comment: @dude8998 If the hyphens cannot be at the beginning and end then use the lighter version.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what about for slashes? And yes the hyphens will likely never be at beginning or end

Comment: @dude8998 Slashes are non-word chars (same as hyphens), so `\b/` will only match in strings like `w/`, `1/` or `_/`, but will not  match in `./` or `a /bcd` NOTE that neither hyphens nor slashes need escaping.

Comment: Great, I will use the lighter version!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but There is a problem, I need to add every word I find to an ArrayList, but this solution doesn't seem to let me determine which word i find, so I cant do that

Comment: See https://ideone.com/xVFuGP. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
String paragraph = "I ate an apple, but I am still hungry, so I will eat pie";
List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList("apple","hungry","pie");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:" + String.join("|", wordList) + ")\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(paragraph);
if (m.find()) {  // To find all matches, replace "if" with "while"
    System.out.println("Found " + m.group()); // => Found apple
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/xVFuGP).

The regex will look like `\b(?:word1|word2|wordN)\b` and will match:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:word1|word2|wordN)` - any of the alternatives inside the non-capturing group
- `\b` - a word boundary

Since you say the characters in the words can only be uppercase letters, digits and hyphens with slashes, none of them need escaping, so `Pattern.quote` is not important here. Also, since the slashes and hyphens will never appear at the start/end of the string, you won't have issues usually caused by `\b` word boundary. Otherwise, replace the first `"\\b"` with `"(?<!\\w)"` and the last one with `"(?!\\w)"`.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, but this will find every match fro every word if I do the while, can it go further and only find the first match for each word?

Comment: Also, the heavy solution is getting me to run out of memory, any idea why? I'm outputting using String builders I understand that cant take up memory

Comment: @dude8998 No, either all or the first from the group. What is the real  life scenario?

Comment: So in real life, I am given an all uppercase paragraph that could be any length. I'm also given a list of uppercase words. I want to find if a paragraph contains words and put every word match into a list. So if I have the sentence `"I ate an apple, but I am still hungry, so I will eat pie pie pie pie"` the word `pie` will only be added once when looking for `pie`, and it will also search for `apple` and `hungry` and put those in the list too

Comment: @dude8998 Use `while` but [add all matches to a **`set`**](https://ideone.com/PjnDy3).

Comment: Would using a HashSet instead of ArrayList really amke a big difference?

Comment: If you want distinct values, yes.

Comment: @dude8998 Please consider also upvoting if the answer proved helpful to you (you are entitled to upvoting after reaching 5 rep points).